# Jquery Click trigger another Div - Easy

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I think this is probably a pretty easy question, I think I've been staring at this for to long.

Basically, how can I get this 'click' event on one div to trigger the other div to move.

```
$(".button").click(function () {
  $(.green).toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
});
```

I know it works like this

```
$(".button").click(function () {
  $(this).toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
});
```

But I don't want that .button to slide, I want the .green to slide on click of .button.

Make sense?

http://jsfiddle.net/Hdern/3/

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
$(.green)
```

should be :

```
$('.green')
```

to reference an element by class (or anything else, except variables), you pass a quoted string.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hdern/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot quotes:

```
$(".button").click(function () {
  $('.green').toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".button").click(function () {
  $(".green").toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);//Missing quotes
});
```